# Number of integer solution of system of nonlinear equations

Tags: number-theory

How many ordered four-tuples of integers $(a, b, c, d)$ with $ 0 < a < b < c < d < 500$ satisfy $a + d = b + c$ and $bc - ad = 93$?

My idea is set $a+d=b+c=k$ but it lead to a lot of annoying casework. Is there any fast way to solve for the tuples or to prove none such tuples exist? Thank you！

Comment: hint: bc and ad are congruent mod a divisor of 93.

Comment: $$bc-d(b+c-d)=93$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee So how can we use this fact? I am really bad at these kind of multi variable problems... Do we take out 93 from bc and ad and say      bc/93-ad/93=1? But how will that help?

Comment: I was just showing there's more information than you think. the congruence was to eliminate possibilities mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: You can express $c$ and $d$ based on $a$ and $b$ from the above equations such as follow:

$$c = \frac{ab - a^2 + 93}{b - a}$$
$$d = \frac{b^2 - ab + 93}{b - a}$$

Hence, $b-a|ab-a^2+93 \Rightarrow b-a|93$ and $b-a|b^2-ab+93$.

Comment: From your first equation follows $c = \frac{ab - a^2 + 93}{b - a}=a+\frac{93}{b-a}$ so $(b-a)|93$

Answer (score 0):

multiply equality $a+d=b+c$ from both sides on $d$ and use that $ad=bc-93$. So, we have: $$bc-93+d^2=bd+cd$$ $$(b-d)(c-d)=93$$

As, $a,b,c,d$ - integers and $0<a<b<c<d<500$, we left with $$b-d=-31;c-d=-3$$ and $$b-d=-93;c-d=-1$$, also by adding we get that $b+c-2d=a-d=-34$ and for the second case $a-d=-94.$ So, you left with: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a-d=-34; &  & \\ 
b-d=-31;&  & \\
c-d=-3.&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ or $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a-d=-94; &  & \\ 
b-d=-93;&  & \\
c-d=-1.&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Let us consider first system. from here:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a=d-34; &  & \\ 
b=d-31;&  & \\
c=d-3.&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
From here, $d-34<d-31<d-3<d$. Then for any integer $d\in[35;499]$, we have the solutions. Check, for example some of them: $$1<4<32<35$$ $$2<5<33<36$$ $$3<6<34<37$$ $$...$$ $$465<468<496<499$$

The second system is left for you...

Comment: we already have a hint posted by OmG. I can't see the benefit of an additional hint  even if you added some steps. Maybe it makes sense to add the complete solution.